# Prove $(a+b)^\frac{1}{n} \le a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality

Prove:
$$
(a+b)^\frac{1}{n} \le a^\frac{1}{n} + b^\frac{1}{n}, \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
I have have tried using the triangle inequlity $ |a + b| \le |a| + |b| $,  without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be positive? Then this inequaltiy is equivalent to $a + b \le (a^{1/n} + b^{1/n})^n$, which follows immediately from expanding the term on the right-hand side with the binomial theorem.

Comment: +1, as I see no reason to not vote up an answer that took as much effort (in an attempt to peacefully counter the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731)) ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** (Assuming $a,b$ positive) Binomial theorem.

> let $c=a^{1/n}$, $d=b^{1/n}$. We want $$c^n+d^n\leq(c+d)^n.$$ By the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), the RHS contains the LHS plus more positive terms.

Comment: +1But why the link does not disappear by default? is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. On Chrome it dissappears, on Firefox not. It certainly has been fixed once: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D%5Bspoilers%5D+is%3Aq+link You can report the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You can show (equivalent) that $x\mapsto \sqrt[n]{x}$ is subadditive.

Comment: I don't see how this is related..

Comment: @barto Thanks, i mean _subadditive_.

Comment: Ehm.. How is this not just a reformulation?